# TIME(n) versus TIME(nlogn)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity

The time hierarchy theorem implies TIME($n$) is strictly contained in TIME($n\log^{1+ε}n$) for all ε>0. Is the relationship between TIME($n$) and TIME($nlogn$) known?

Comment: On a single tape machine, the non-regular language $\{A^nB^n | n \geq 0\}$ is easily decidable in TIME[$O(n \log n)$], but all languages decidable in TIME[$o(n \log n)$] are regular. This same argument does *not* work for multi-tape machines.

Comment: of course, my model of computation is multi-tape Turing machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $a≥0$ and $ε>0$, $\mathrm{DTIME}(O(n \log^{a} n))$ is strictly contained in $\mathrm{DTIME}(O(n \log^{a+ε} n))$; see my answer [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5297/justification-of-log-f-in-dtime-hierarchy-theorem/39062#39062).

To recap, the logarithmic overhead comes from tape reduction (and is not needed if the number of tapes is fixed and is at least two).  There is a nonconstructive argument that converts the logarithmic overhead into time hierarchy at $\log^{ε} \mathrm{time}$ multiplicative precision for well-behaved (time-constructible and in a certain sense continuous) time bounds.

A constructive proof of the strict inclusion of $\mathrm{DTIME}(O(n))$ in $\mathrm{DTIME}(O(n \log n))$ remains (to my knowledge) an open problem.

Comment: I've checked out your answer and it's nice. But could you elaborate a little bit more about how to use the padding argument?

Comment: Also, where does the proof require that f is well-behaved in your sense?

Comment: For time-constructible $f(n) > n$, if $\mathrm{Time}(O(f(n))) = \mathrm{Time}(O(n))$, then by padding input to length $f(n)$, $\mathrm{Time}(O(f(f(n)))) = \mathrm{Time}(O(f(n)))$ (and similarly with appropriate $g(n)$ in place of $n$).  The 'continuity' of a function $g$ is used to get from $g$ to $>g \log g$ using a finite composition of $f$ with $f(g(n)) < g(n) \log^ε g(n)$.