# Computational Complexity of RESTRICTED primality testing

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, time-complexity, nt.number-theory

*Input*: Any number $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ that can be represented in the form of $n = 2^a + b,\ |b|= c $. 
*output*: **YES** if $n$ is prime , else **NO** .

Now, length of binary input is $\log(a) + O(1)$ which otherwise would be order $a$.
What would be the complexity of such problem? If we use *AKS algorithm*  in straight forward way we would not get polynomial time algorithm, I think. Can we define new problems by tweaking the standard problems in  **P** to make them harder in this way i.e. by restricting the input in certain way.

Comment: The succinct version of problems are exponentially harder (e.g. Succinct-SAT is NExpTime-complete). Yours is a restricted case of succinct version of Prime.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that succinct version of problems is already well explored area.

Comment: You are welcome. ps: You may want to have a look at [Russell Impagliazzo's answer to the padding question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2453/186).

Comment: @Kaveh make this an answer ?